# Why subview controller did not load when assign it to a parent view?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uitableview, subview

I am trying to add a table view as a subview of a normal view. However, I need complex control of the table view. Here are my related codes:

```
// In ParentViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    _mytbvc= [[TableViewController alloc] init];
    _mytbvc.tableView = self.tableview;
    // 1 Way I tried:
    [self addChildViewController:_mytbvc];
    [self.view addSubview:_mytbvc.tableView];
    [_mytbvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    // Another way I tried
//    self.tableview.delegate = _mytbvc;
//    self.tableview.dataSource = _mytbvc;
//    self.textfield.delegate = self;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


//In TableViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"table view loaded");
    if (_messages == nil){
        _messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self setEditing:true];
    [self setEditing:true];
    NSLog(@"%lu", _messages.count);
}
```

The problem I found currently is that the program does not even run the `viewDidLoad` method in `TableViewController`. Any idea which part might be wrong? What should I look into?

Comment: Do you have a typo in your question, or do you really have a class TableViewController (which is where your viewDidLoad method is), because the one you're adding is a LocColChatTableViewController

Comment: @rdelmar: I changed my class names to TableViewController so that might be easier to understand.

Comment: Are you using a Storyboard to build the tableview ?  Can't see the alloc so assume you are doing this ?

Comment: @Aardvark: yes, I am using a storyboard, where in a view, I added a tableview and some labels. I am trying to assign a table view controller to manage that tableview.

Comment: What is the definition of TableViewController ?  @interface TableViewController : UITableViewController ?

Comment: When you use Storyboard and create a new File, NewFile, Objective-C class in XCode this should be done for you ?

Comment: @Aardvark: yes. My definition is TableViewController : UITableViewController. Do you think I should not use this way? Instead do sth like ViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42265/discussion-between-aardvark-and-yitong-zhou)